# Is there a way to split an image without changing its final size?

Tags: images, tools

I want to split an image to an **n** number of images, each new generated one must has the same size of the original image with a black background for the rest of the image, look at the example I provided:

the original Image:

[image]

So, I want a way to split it to let's say **three** equal parts, So, I want the result to be like the following :

[image]

[image]

[image]

is there's a tool exists or a way to achieve that?

Comment: Mmm... Imagemagick [crop](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/) can simply handle the split, but leaving the original position in canvas works only with gif (e.g. *convert yourimage.jpg -crop 1x3@ +adjoin out_%d.gif*) and turning the canvas in solid color is a bit tricky to do in just a command. However, you can try to do it in more steps.

Comment: it's somthing like a Moving Black Mask over the image. If i where you I would make an Action with an Animated mask from top to bottom and export the result in every movment.

Answer (score 1):

you can use **Slice Tool** to split the image in parts, than **Save for Web**, which outputs several sliced image files, than you can **drag & drop** above files into the same project as layers on top of black background, **realign** them to resemble the original image using **Snap** and **Snap To** and turn the slice layers visibility on/off, saving the result.

when cutting image using Slice Tool, each slice has an X Y coordinate, you can check it by clicking **right mouse button > slice options**, when **Slice Tool** is active. to realign exactly, hit **ctrl+t** to transform slice layer and enter X Y coordinates & set up reference point location.

if you want to split an images into 100x parts, you gonna have a hard time realigning manually though. automating the above method via script would be a way to go